# How to write conditional recursive types on an object in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursive-type

I have following four types

Type T1

```
export type T1 = "p" | "q" | "r" | "a" | "b";
```

Type T2

```
export type T2 = {
  h: string;
  hc: {};
};
```

Interface Def

```
export interface Def {
  [k: string]: {
    [K in T1 | "abc"]?: K extends T1
      ? T2
      : {
          [k in T1]?: T2;
        };
  };
}
```

Interface A

```
export interface A {
  name: string;
  def: Def;
}
```

The usage should be like follows

```
const x: A = {
  name: "test",
  def: {
    xxx: {
      p: {
        h: "s",
        hc: {
         
        },
      },
      abc: {
        p: {
          h: "s",
          hc: {
            
          },
        },
        abc: {
          p: {
            h: "s",
            hc: {
              
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

The problem I am having is that if the object of type Def with in attribute xxx has property abc then it should recursively accept the abc object again as above example. I tried calling `Def` recursively but that does not work.

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mL2A4w) what you're looking for? If so I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Hey @jcalz string | string is a mistake it should be string. and your solution is what I was looking for. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest writing `Def` like

```
interface Def {
  [k: string]: DefEntry
}
```

where `DefEntry` is a recursive object type:

```
type DefEntry =
  { [K in T1]?: T2 } & // this is equivalent to Partial<Record<T1, T2>>
  { abc?: DefEntry };
```

or, equivalently, you could write `DefEntry` as a recursive interface like

```
interface DefEntry extends Partial<Record<T1, T2>> {
  abc?: DefEntry
}
```

In neither case is [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) like `K extends T1 ? T2 : ...` necessary.

---

And that makes your `A` interface and the test value work as desired:

```
const x: A = { // okay
  name: "test",
  def: {
    xxx: {
      p: { h: "s", hc: {}, },
      abc: {
        p: { h: "s", hc: {}, },
        abc: {
          p: { h: "s", hc: {}, },
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqBGOBeOAiMPOAH3wEcjS8pL8BDWvAIzwG4BYAKC69ElgTJUaAEw44Aby5w4ACwBccAM4woASwB2Acw6cZsgMaKJAX11menAPQAqJCjgARYADMAohtWIc0yXADaANJwmugYALoA-IqicCZwAGS+EnB0TAbRTq4eXnG6NlaWmjDAUC50BqjO7p5Q3qAlGgAmSnAACnSwanQANgA8AErABtBNfZgANOgiAHwzkr5pGYrVOXVcJpZ80PDFpeWVWS4LegEA1ooq6trhK9m1iBtb4DshnvsVqACCJzIadABbYCXVSaHS+JquO4ucyWLgjDQqOAgRQ-XApKxWOAQM50R6nf5AxR4EoqPATCFQ34yZEgFHUmlwMDGOTEpTkuRGSQmKY83yMpbGfmMpkshT4dlTQzGHlxCmnEWpdJChWK0V+cV4SWcmW8+VquXCmR81Um43ysxwLhAA)